# Insert tags in a python string using positions

Tags: python, html, tags

I have a python string and a tuple/list of tuples representing the position of the subsequence to tag and the name of the tag:

```
text = "This is an example"
label = (0, 4, "tag1")

# Expected result
> "<tag1>This</tag1> is an example"
```

Another example:

```
text = "This is a more complicated example"
labels = [(0, 7, "tag1"),
          (5, 7, "tag2"),
          (10, 14, "tags3")]

# Expected result
> "<tag1>This <tag2>is</tag2></tag1> a <tag3>more</tag3> complicated example"
```

How to insert a tag at the specified positions?

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Comment: Think String Slicing and go from there. This should have a fairly straightforward implementation.